# How to detect iOS back swipe gesture in Flutter MaterialApp?

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, swipe, gesture

I want to detect when the user uses the back swipe gesture in my iOS App. How can I do it?

I created CupertinoPageRoute hoping that it would somehow work with it...

```
    return MaterialApp(
        initialRoute: AllProductsScreen.id,

        onGenerateRoute: (RouteSettings settings) {
          switch (settings.name) {
            case AllProductsScreen.id:
              return CupertinoPageRoute(
                  builder: (_) => AllProductsScreen(), settings: settings);
            case ProductScreen.id:
              return CupertinoPageRoute(
                  builder: (_) => ProductScreen(), settings: settings);
            case FavoritesScreen.id:
              return CupertinoPageRoute(
                  builder: (_) => FavoritesScreen(), settings: settings);
            default:
              return CupertinoPageRoute(
                  builder: (_) => AllProductsScreen(), settings: settings);
          }
        },
      );
```

Comment: Do you need to know if the gesture is used to pop the page or just event when the page is popped?

Comment: I need the event when the page is popped to start a function.

Comment: Then this is an XY Question and you are asking about the wrong thing. You want to detect when the current page is being navigated away from, so you want to look into `RouteAware` and `RouteObserver`.

Comment: @Abion47 You are right. Thank you very much. I used the solution explained in this post: https://medium.com/koahealth/how-to-track-screen-transitions-in-flutter-with-routeobserver-733984a90dea

Answer (score 0):

If you need to track the current page of the app instead of overriding the back gesture, you might want to consider tracking the current screen using RouteObserver. Here's a [guide](https://medium.flutterdevs.com/tracking-screen-transition-by-route-observer-flutter-dadd8773699c) on setting up a RouteObserver that you can follow.